# How to automate captcha using webdriver on azure ?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, captcha

How can I automate a captcha on azure using webdriver ? Are there any 3rd party tools available ?

Comment: The whole purpose of having captchas for verification is defied if bots can read / automate it.

Comment: By disabling it for test environments.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to automate captcha using selenium web driver. There are few tools like `Tesseract OCR` which helps to retrieve the text from the image.But still, it will not be able to recognize the font used for captcha in azure site.